# javascript how to fire change or input event in paste event handler

Tags: javascript, events, onchange, paste

I override paste event on document object, now i want to fire `onchange`, `oninput` and other input events in event handler for `paste` event.

```
document.addEventListener('paste', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var copiedText = e.clipboardData.getData("text/plain");

    if (e.srcElement.type === 'text' || e.srcElement.type === 'textarea') {
        var startPosition = e.srcElement.selectionStart;
        var endPosition = e.srcElement.selectionEnd;
        var len = e.srcElement.value.length;
        var sel = e.srcElement.value.substring(startPosition, endPosition);

        e.srcElement.value = e.srcElement.value.substring(0, startPosition) + copiedText +
            e.srcElement.value.substring(endPosition, len);
    }



    $(e.srcElement).trigger("change");
    $(e.srcElement).trigger("input");
    $(e.srcElement).trigger("propertychange");


});
```

How can I fire `change`, `input` or `propertychange` event for input element?

This part of code dose not work.

```
    $(e.srcElement).trigger("change");
    $(e.srcElement).trigger("input");
    $(e.srcElement).trigger("propertychange");
```

Comment: select event target element with $(e.target)  ex. $(e.target).css('background-color','red');

Answer (score 0):

`$(e.srcElement).change();` will fire the change event ant its handlers but not sure about `input` and `propertychange`

Comment: sorry, i tested this before ask question not working

Comment: how about `$(e.target).change();`